# What would be a simple and good way to tell Selenium python in what page i'm at?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make that selenium would check a list of elements

```
page_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('login')
page_2 = driver.find_element_by_class('lead-in')
page_3 = driver.find_element_by_name('Submit')
```

And whenever selenium detects that the object inside variable is located in the running driver I could then run specific steps after it finds one of the elements in "page_1,page_2,page_3"

I want to create it so that my bot can understand on what step of my prorgramm it is because the website doesn't change the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.title
driver.current_url
```

these properties returns the page title and the current url ,you cna use them to determine which page you are in . You can also check for  some specific element to know if you are in that page.

use find elements , and check if size of array >  zero,

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('login')
driver.find_elements_by_class('lead-in')
driver.find_elements_by_name('Submit')
```

Comment: Yes, but for my specific program the title doesn't change for 90% of the pages. The thing I want to do is create a def that will run always and check for the page in ascending order (I guess the best way for it to be done is by creating variables that is defined with the element, as the example in my question and let python just run through it all the time, and whenever I reach a specific page then another def or a class will run and do something else)

Comment: what about url ?

Comment: how do you check whether you are in page what criteria you look for

Comment: Can't give the url. I check with EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID, ""))

Comment: I meant can;t you check if url changed for each page

Comment: I can see, it doesn't change

Comment: use find_elements instead and check if returning list has size greater than 0

Comment: if it is the n you are in that particular page